# python code for mininet commands

Tags: python, command, mininet

I'm doing a project using mininet, and I need to write a python code that can do multiple pings and iperfs at the same time. I'm trying to execute the commands through python but every time i'm getting errors. can anyone give a simple example on how to write a program that can do a single ping or iperf and show the resaults somewhere, i'll be very thankful to him/her.

Comment: https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Mininet-api-documentation

Comment: Mininet has an example on multiple ping. Here is the link: https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/examples/multiping.py